# jQuery horizontal page scrolling

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, slide

I'm searching for something like this.

http://www.sc5.fi/#clients

When you click the links on the top of the page, it will load a new page with Ajax (I'm not sure does that one do that, but that's what I want) and it will slide or scroll to it.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the are using this code right here:

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/create-a-funky-parallax-background-effect-using-jquery/

Greetings